# How to round float number with while loop in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, precision

I have a rather unorthodox homework assignment where I am to write a simple function where a `double` value is rounded to an integer with using only a `while` loop.

The main goal is to write something similar to the round function.
I made some progress where I should add or subtract a very small `double` value and I would eventually hit a number that will become an integer:

```
while(~isinteger(inumberup))
    inumberup=inumberup+realmin('double');
end
```

However, this results in a never-ending loop.  Is there a way to accomplish this task?

I'm not allowed to use `round`, `ceil`, `floor`, `for`, `rem` or `mod` for this question.

Comment: `isinteger` checks for value type - default MATLAB type is double. `isinteger(5)` returns `0`. Is [`fix`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) banned?

Comment: I think yes, there is written that I have to use while loop for that :D My power is far beyond this level :D

Comment: `fix` is similar to `floor` but it rounds towards zero.  `floor` rounds towards minus infinity... so yes I would think that `fix` is banned too.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `abs`?

Comment: Yes I am, my teacher didn't mention that abs is banned

Comment: What exactly is the criteria for "integer" in the assignment? It has to be within some tolerance of the actual integer, you can't get an integer from a float without a type conversion so `isinteger` is never going to work.

Comment: @MaciejCiach Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

**Assumption:** `if` statements and the `abs` function are allowed as the list of forbidden functions does not include this.

---

Here's one solution.  What you can do is keep subtracting the input value by 1 until you get to a point where it becomes less than 1.  The number produced after this point is the **fractional component of the number** (i.e. if our number was 3.4, the fractional component is 0.4).  You would then check to see if the fractional component, which we will call `f`, is less than 0.5.  If it is, that means you need to round down and so you would subtract the input number with `f`.  If the number is larger than 0.5 or equal to 0.5, you would **add** the input number by `(1 - f)` in order to go up to the next highest number.  However, this only handles the case for positive values.  For negative values, `round` in MATLAB rounds towards negative infinity, so what we ought to do is take the **absolute** value of the input number and do this subtraction to find the fractional part.

Once we do this, we then check to see what the fractional part is equal to, and then depending on the sign of the number, we either add or subtract accordingly.  If the fractional part is less than 0.5 and if the number is positive, we need to subtract by `f` else we need to add by `f`.  If the fractional part is greater than or equal to 0.5, if the number is positive we need to add by `(1 - f)`, else we subtract by `(1 - f)`

Therefore, assuming that `num` is the input number of interest, you would do:

```
function out = round_hack(num)

%// Repeatedly subtract until we get a value that less than 1
%// i.e. the fractional part
%// Also make sure to take the absolute value
f = abs(num);
while f > 1
    f = f - 1;
end

%// Case where we need to round down
if f < 0.5
    if num > 0
        out = num - f;
    else
        out = num + f;
    end
%// Case where we need to round up
else
    if num > 0        
        out = num + (1 - f);
    else
        out = num - (1 - f);
    end
end
```

Be advised that this will be slow for larger values of `num`.  I've also wrapped this into a function for ease of debugging.  Here are a few example runs:

```
>> round_hack(29.1)

ans =

    29

>> round_hack(29.6)

ans =

    30

>> round_hack(3.4)

ans =

     3

>> round_hack(3.5)

ans =

     4

>> round_hack(-0.4)

ans =

     0

>> round_hack(-0.6)

ans =

    -1

>> round_hack(-29.7)

ans =

   -30
```

You can check that this agrees with MATLAB's `round` function for the above test cases.

Comment: You could also just implement the [modulo series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Series_expansions)

Comment: @excaza Hm... the series expansion is undefined for an input that is actually an integer.

Comment: Testing for integers is not prohibited

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without loop: you can use `num2str` to convert the number into a string, then find the position of the `.` in the string and extract the string fron its beginning up to the position of the `.`; then you convert it back to a numebr with `str2num`

To round it you have to check the value of the first char (converted into a number) after the `.`.

```
r=rand*100
s=num2str(r)
idx=strfind(num2str(r),'.')
v=str2num(s(idx+1))
if(v <= 5)
   rounded_val=str2num(s(1:idx-1))
else
   rounded_val=str2num(s(1:idx-1))+1
end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: I also had this idea, but it is strictly written in the exercise to use while loop :/